# Hiding button on a particular tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, button, tableview, uitableview

**Background:**

My code displays a list of food items in a `tableview`, and in a `UITableViewCell` there is a `button` to add the food items to cart as needed. 
When a particular item is added to cart, the add `button` corresponding to that `cell` should be hidden and rest all which are not added should not be hidden.

**Problem:**

The problem is, when I add an item say which is at `index: 0` to cart, it gets added successfully and `button` is hidden, but when I click on second `button` which is at `index : 1`, second item also gets added to cart but the first item button becomes unhidden, at a time only one button which is at the current index is getting hidden instead of all the item buttons which are added to cart.

```
   func addToCart(_ button : UIButton) {
        self.selectedIndex = button.tag            
        let foodItem : HCFoodItem = arrFoodItems?.object(at: self.selectedIndex) as! HCFoodItem
        foodItem.isFoodAddedToCart = true
        arrItemsAddedToCart?.add(foodItem)
        let arrayCount  = arrItemsAddedToCart?.count
        let badgeCount : String = String(format: "%d", arrayCount!)
        tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.last?.badgeValue = badgeCount
        HCDataCache.sharedDataCacheInstance.cacheData(object: arrItemsAddedToCart, key: HC_CACHE_KEY_CART_ITEM)
        self.foodItemsTableView?.reloadData()

    }

 // hide/unhide buttons here...

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellId: NSString = "LazyLoadTableViewCell"

        var foodItems : HCFoodItem?
        foodItems = arrFoodItems?.object(at: indexPath.row) as! HCFoodItem?
        let cell: HCFoodItemTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId as String)! as! HCFoodItemTableViewCell

        cell.imgFood?.downloadImageFrom(link: foodItems?.strFoodImage as! String, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill)

        cell.btnAddDelete?.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnAddDelete?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HCHomeViewController.addToCart(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        let itemsAddedToCart : NSMutableArray? = HCDataCache.sharedDataCacheInstance.fetchCachedDataForKey(key: HC_CACHE_KEY_CART_ITEM)

        if (itemsAddedToCart?.count)! > 0 {
            for cardFoodItem in itemsAddedToCart!{
                let  foodItem : HCFoodItem = cardFoodItem as! HCFoodItem
                if foodItem.strFoodName == foodItems?.strFoodName {
                    cell.btnAddDelete?.isHidden = true
                }else{
                    cell.btnAddDelete?.isHidden = false
                }


            }
        } else {
            cell.btnAddDelete?.isHidden = false
        }            
        cell.selectionStyle = .none    
        return cell  
    }
```

Comment: Since you didn't show your `HCFoodItem` class code you need to add one more property in that class called `shouldShowBtn` and when you add object set that property to `false` and into your `cellForRowAt` hide and show your button according to `shouldShowBtn` flag.

Comment: check your cache data array, you are adding again and again so  replace it with index

        arrItemsAddedToCart?.add(foodItem)
 Instead of this, u use replace array value at index. try once

Comment: is button also unhide when scroll ?

Comment: you no need to run the for loop inside the "cellForRowAt indexPath", Just put a BOOL property in HCFoodItem and turn to yes when you add item to the cart. So on the basis of this property you can hide/show the button in "cellForRowAt indexPath".

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich , No button is not unhiding while scroll

Comment: You need to comply with MVC pattern in order to do this properly. You need to change the data first, and then update the cell accordingly by reloadrows method.

Comment: can you verify the itemsAddedToCart?.count after adding multiple items into cart?